# Active Record issue with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sidekiq

I have created a Query resource in rails. When a Query is POSTed, I create Query record and fire 2 task workers in the background using Sidekiq.
My query model in addition to having the query parameters also contains status for each of the task workers. At the time of Query creation, the status for each task is set to "created".

```
 @query = Query.create(param1: parameter1, param2: parameter2, task1_status: "created", task2_status: "created") 

 Task1Worker.perform_async(@query.id)
 Task2Worker.perform_async(@query.id)
```

Task1 worker uses the query parameters to perform some processing and based on the results updates the task_status to either "completed" or "failed"

```
 q = Query.find(query_id)
 status = process_task1()
 if status == SUCCESS
   q.task1_status = "completed"
 else
   q.task1_status = "failed"
 end   
 q.save!
```

Task2 worker waits for Task1 to be completed before starting processing

```
 q = Query.find(query_id)
 count = 1
 while q.task1_status == "created"
   if count == 3
     logger.error("Task1 state change timed out")
     return
   end
   sleep(5)
   q = Query.find(query_id)
 end   
 status = process_task2()
 if status == SUCCESS
   q.task2_status = "completed"
 else
   q.task2_status = "failed"
 end   
 q.save!
```

Task 1 needs about 4 secs for the processing and sets the state to either "completed" or "failed". But Task 2 never sees the update & times out after 10 secs, without processing. Is there something I am missing here. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But Task 2 never sees the update & times out after 10 secs, without processing

I'm suspecting caching problems (`Query.find(query_id)` hitting cache and not database). Try using `q.reload` instead of `q = Query.find(query_id)` on each retry.

Or, much better, schedule Task2 from Task1 when it completes, so that you don't have to tie your worker for long periods of time doing *nothing*.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Sergio.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
3.times do |count|
  logger.error("Task1 state change timed out") and return if count == 2
  if (q = Query.find(query_id)).task1_status != 'created'
    q.task2_status = process_task2() == SUCCESS ? 'completed' : 'failed'
    q.save!
  end
  sleep(5)
end
```

Comment: How it should help with the problem? Nicer code, yes, but it does the same thing and will fail in the same way

Comment: I don't know, I found `while q.task1_status == "created"` suspicious, so checking `task1_status` on the found object directly instead of declaring it outside and assigning it inside the loop..and can't really reproduce it as it is non-verifiable.